# multi-part identifier could not be bound on where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

hi below is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsRegionNameAllowed] (@RegionName VARCHAR(200),
                                             @RegionId   INT)
AS
  BEGIN
      --Region Name Duplicate Check
      DECLARE @IsExist BIT

      SET @IsExist=0

      IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT EntityID,
                                        ResultObject.value('
                    declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LPSFS.Entity";
                    (/RegionQueueEntity/Region/RegionName)[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS RegionName
                        FROM   TransactionLPS t
                               JOIN servistreammyqueue my
                                 ON t.servistreamtransactionid = my.servistreammyqueueid
                               JOIN lkpqueuestatus lkp
                                 ON my.queuestatusid = lkp.queuestatusid
                        WHERE  SubContextID IN (SELECT ContextID
                                                FROM   lkpcontext
                                                WHERE  ContextCode = 'RGMCTX0002')
                               AND EntityID <> @RegionId) AS RegName
                WHERE  ( lower(RegName.RegionName) = lower(@RegionName)
                         AND lkp.queuestatuscode = 'QSTAPP' ))
        SET @IsExist=1
  END
```

but it is giving an error in lkp.queuestatuscode,that (multi-part identifier could not be bound).
please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lkp` is an alias in the subquery. It no longer exists for the `WHERE` clause of the outer query. If you want to query it in the outer `WHERE` clause, then include it in the subselect's `SELECT` clause, and observe the fact that the alias for the subquery is `RegName`, not `lkp`:

```
Select * from (
select distinct EntityID,
                  ResultObject.value('
                    declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LPSFS.Entity";
                    (/RegionQueueEntity/Region/RegionName)[1]','varchar(200)') as RegionName
       ,lkp.queuestatuscode
            from TransactionLPS t
            join servistreammyqueue my on t.servistreamtransactionid = my.servistreammyqueueid
            join lkpqueuestatus lkp on my.queuestatusid = lkp.queuestatusid
            where SubContextID in (Select ContextID from lkpcontext where ContextCode = 'RGMCTX0002')
            And EntityID <> @RegionId) as RegName
Where (lower(RegName.RegionName)=lower(@RegionName) And RegName.queuestatuscode = 'QSTAPP'))
```

Also, since all of this is being used in an `EXISTS` test, I would remove the `DISTINCT` - at best, it's redundant, at worst it may cause the system to produce a less than optimial plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsRegionNameAllowed]
(
      @RegionName varchar(200)
    , @RegionId int
)
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @IsExist BIT
SELECT @IsExist = 0

IF EXISTS( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            EntityID,
            ResultObject.value('
                            declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LPSFS.Entity";
                            (/RegionQueueEntity/Region/RegionName)[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS RegionName
        FROM dbo.TransactionLPS t
        JOIN dbo.servistreammyqueue my ON t.servistreamtransactionid = my.servistreammyqueueid
        JOIN dbo.lkpqueuestatus lkp ON my.queuestatusid = lkp.queuestatusid
        WHERE EntityID <> @RegionId
            AND lkp.queuestatuscode = 'QSTAPP'
            AND SubContextID IN (
                            SELECT t2.ContextID 
                            FROM lkpcontext t2
                            WHERE t2.ContextCode = 'RGMCTX0002'
                        )
    ) RegName
    WHERE lower(RegName.RegionName) = lower(@RegionName) 
) SELECT @IsExist = 1

END
```